# ChartJS 2.6 - Bar chart fixed height scrollable-X

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm having trouble trying to figure out the correct setup to have a ChartJS Bar Chart that has a fixed canvas height but allows the width be overflow-x.  I have found an example here...http://jsfiddle.net/mbhavfwm/ which uses ChartJS 1.0, but I'm using ChartJS 2.6.  So, I found another example here http://jsfiddle.net/jmpxgufu/ which uses ChartJS 2, but this example shows the chart rendered with only a few values and then ADDS more to it using javascript which then causes the width to overflow.  Not quite the same.

My problem is I can not figure out how to make the chart render at the fixed height with all the data already in it, but NOT try to constrain the canvas to the width of the parent container.  I want it to overflow.

Here is what I have so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/fed79b7t/

**HTML**

```
<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
    <canvas id="chart-FuelSpend" height="300" width="1200"></canvas>
  </div>
  <canvas id="axis-FuelSpend" height="300" width="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function generateLabels() {
  var chartLabels = [];
  for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    chartLabels.push("Label" + x);
  }
  return chartLabels;
}

function generateData() {
  var chartData = [];
  for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    chartData.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
  }
  return chartData;
}

var chartData = {
  labels: generateLabels(),
  datasets: [{
    label: "Test Data Set",
    data: generateData()
  }]
};

$(function() {
  var canvasFuelSpend = $('#chart-FuelSpend');
  var chartFuelSpend = new Chart(canvasFuelSpend, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        titleFontSize: 0,
        titleMarginBottom: 0,
        bodyFontSize: 12
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 12,
            display: false
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 12,
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      },
      animation: {
        onComplete: function() {
          var sourceCanvas = chartFuelSpend.chart.canvas;
          var copyWidth = chartFuelSpend.scales['y-axis-0'].width - 10;
          var copyHeight = chartFuelSpend.scales['y-axis-0'].height + chartFuelSpend.scales['y-axis-0'].top + 10;
          var targetCtx = document.getElementById("axis-FuelSpend").getContext("2d");
          targetCtx.canvas.width = copyWidth;
          targetCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight, 0, 0, copyWidth, copyHeight);
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

So, my goal is to have the chart the full 1200 pixels as defined by the canvas width, but for the container div to only show the 600 pixel amount where I can scroll the container to see the rest of the chart while keeping the Y-axis in place.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?  What am I missing?

Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have something to do with the fact you're missing a wrapper around the `canvas`. Here's an updated version of your fiddle. I've added a `function` called `addData` that takes the number of new entries you want to add and the `chart` variable. It's not as good as it can be (because i'm not 100% sure how you want to add new data) but it's a great starting point. The trick is to not initialize the `chart` with all `data` included, you want to create the `chart` and then add to it later to expand the canvas, otherwise the initial render will work to fit all of the `data` in at that `width`.

https://jsfiddle.net/qmqmg82z/3/

Additional JavaScript code:

```
function addData(numData, chart){
    for (var i = 0; i < numData; i++){
        chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
        chart.data.labels.push("Label" + i);
        var newwidth = $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width() +60;
        $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);
    }
}
```

and then at the end of your page load function (or wherever you want to be adding new data) add this function call:

```
addData(5, chartFuelSpend);
```

But bear in mind this will require however much data you want to add and the `chart` instance.

And the HTML:

```
<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
      <div class="chartAreaWrapper2">
          <canvas id="chart-FuelSpend" height="300" width="1200"></canvas>
      </div>
  </div>
  <canvas id="axis-FuelSpend" height="300" width="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

I'm guessing the problem was that because the `width` of the single wrapper you had was changing along with the `chart`, it meant that the horizontal scroll wasn't being applied, this way the outer wrapper has the fixed `width` while the inside one and the canvas can expand.

Comment: thank you as I can see how I can use this to add data to the chart making it scrollable.  However, the amount of data I would be adding could be hundreds of columns.  If you look at your example and change the count passed to the addData method to something like 100 or larger, you'll see the chart grows in height which is not what I want.  The height must stay fixed.  Any ideas?

Comment: I was hoping I could set the maxTicksLimit on the yaxis to limit the number of ticks and maybe prevent the height from growing, but not luck.  It still grows with the more data I add.

Comment: Yeah, seems strange, if you console.log(chart.height) in the for loop within addData() it even says the height of the canvas stays the same :S. Only thing I can think of is that it might be a rendering issue with Chart JS that causes the contents of the canvas to expand beyond what it should.

Comment: interesting...why does this example NOT do that?  I can add as many extra to this one as I want and the height stays the same.  http://jsfiddle.net/jmpxgufu/97/

Comment: I really appreciate your input.  It looks like the only way is to create the chart with a subset of the data to be charted, then add the rest after it's rendered.  Marking this as correct.